# How to create a trigger to decrease a counter, what's wrong with my trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012, triggers

I need to decrease a counter in a table schedules, when there was an insert in enrollments table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [UpdateEnrollmentsTrigger]
ON [TBLENROLLMENT_ENR]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ScheduleCode NVARCHAR
    DECLARE @TotalSlots INT

    IF EXISTS(SELECT SCH_CODE FROM inserted)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @ScheduleCode = SCH_CODE FROM inserted

            SELECT @TotalSlots = SCH_TOTALSLOTS FROM TBLSCHEDULES_SCH
            WHERE SCH_CODE = @ScheduleCode

            UPDATE TBLSCHEDULES_SCH
            SET SCH_FREESLOTS = @TotalSlots - 1
            WHERE SCH_CODE = @ScheduleCode
        END
END
```

When I trying to create this trigger, the query window of VS12 says:

```
SQL46010 :: Incorrect syntax near ].
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error is because you are using `FOR INSERT` instead of `AFTER INSERT`, but there are other things that you should improve on your trigger.

First of all, always, always write the length of a `NVARCHAR`, leaving it blank will behave differently depending where it's used. So replace `DECLARE @ScheduleCode NVARCHAR` with `DECLARE @ScheduleCode NVARCHAR(n)`, where `n` is the required length.

I'm also not sure why you are doing the `IF EXISTS` since it's reading the `INSERTED` pseudo table, that it's bound to have records because the trigger was fired.

Another thing to improve is that you are assuming that only one row was inserted, as you are storing it on a variable, that's wrong and it will behave incorrectly if you insert more than just one row.

Oh, I almost forgot, you should also always specify the schema, for instance: `CREATE TRIGGER [UpdateEnrollmentsTrigger] ON [TBLENROLLMENT_ENR]` should be `CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[UpdateEnrollmentsTrigger] ON dbo.[TBLENROLLMENT_ENR]` (using the correct schema, of course)

Comment: I assume that the trigger is triggered for each row inserted. How it work?

Comment: @zerazobz It doesn't work that way. The trigger fires once for the whole `INSERT` transaction. All the inserted rows on the `INSERTED` pseudo table, so you need to be prepared to work with more than just one row, and assume that it's a table with muliple rows (unless every insert operation on that table always insert one row)